# Laravel package return js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I'm developing a `Laravel 5.5` package where I use `vue.js`.

Currently I'm using vue.js code in a script tag in my blade file. I would like to put that in a separated file.

How do I return that file properly?

I already tried this:

**Package service provider**

```
$router->get('js', [
    'uses' => 'AssetController@js',
    'as' => 'underconstruction.js',
]);
```

**Package controller**

```
public function js()
{
    $content = __DIR__ . '/../views/main.vue';

    $response = new Response(
        $content, 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/javascript',
        ]
    );
    return $this->cacheResponse($response);
}
```

Right now when I put this in my blade file:

```
<script src="/js"></script>
```

I get not the file back?
How could I get this working?

Comment: If you are using vue, you can just create `<your-vue-tag parameter="{{$data}}"></your-vue-tag>` then work with `$data` inside your `your-vue-tag.vue` component. You only add the tag with parameters with data for each, nothing more. Show us your blade file pls? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use your route as follows:

```
Route::get('js', 'AssetController@js')->name('underconstruction.js');
```

Also, I see that `$content` variable is only assigned to the file path.
You will need to do something like...

```
$content = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../views/main.vue');
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. But this is not my problem. The problem is that the js is not returned properly.